# Can I wait for location.href to load a page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is it possible to know when a page has loaded using location.href? My current code looks like this and I want to trigger some events to happen once my page has finished loading.  I tried using $.get but it breaks my current implementation of [jquery address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) so this won't work.

```
$('.search').click(function(){
    location.href = "/search.php"; 
    // trigger event here...
    return false;
});
```

This will **NOT** work for my current setup:

```
$.get('search.php', function() {
    alert('Page has finished loading');
});
```

Are there any other options?

Comment: `location.href = "/search.php";` will immediately redirect the browser, and any code after that won't run (or may run until the new page is loaded).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert('Page has finished loading');
});
```

*EDIT: Removed second portion of answer since the purposeful redirect negates it's usefullness*

Comment: I ended up creating a ready script like so: $ready_script = <<<READY_SCRIPT /* trigger my event */ and passed this to the page after the browser redirect.  Seems to work well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Once you change your location, your page unloads.  You cannot run script after doing so.  All you can do is detect when the new page has loaded *within the new page* as @DJ Quimby's answer describes.

An exception is if you change your hash location but stay within the same document.  That can be bound to an event using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

That will simple redirect the browser...

You want to use...

```
$.ajax({ ... });
```

Call using jQuery to call search.php and you can then load the results into a div or something.

Comment: +1. Or, as a temporary solution, he can put in the 'success' callback the actual redirect. It is not orthodox but works out.

Comment: I need it to redirect the browser.  The event gets triggered from inside my header page and then I need to trigger another action on the page.

Comment: @gd1: What would redirecting after using `$.ajax` to get the HTML accomplish?

Comment: As soon as you re-direct the calling page ceases to be... I think you need to expand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Rocket : browser caches the stuff so that if you redirect it'll take less to load the page. But I know this is quite unusual. Better fetching the stuff with .ajax and then put it into a <div>

Comment: Oh sorry guys, I didn't understand he wants to redirect to the page and then continue executing the script. OK, that's impossible. Fine.